# C++ equivalent of .NET's List<>?

Tags: .net

I'm curious as to the most common C++ equivalent to .NET's List<>? There are many libraries, and I'm not sure which one has the best performance characteristics.

Here is the .NET code that demonstrates List<>:

```
List<double> x = new List<double> {1};
x.Add(2);
Console.WriteLine("{0},{1}",x[0], x[1]);
```

Comment: I suggest you search for a [reference site](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp).

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg Thanks. There is so many libraries that its difficult to know where to start.

Comment: @Gravitas: there is only one [standard library for C++](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/) that I am aware of, and only one [add-on library that anybody ever talks about](http://www.boost.org/). A quick search for C++ libraries reveals this fact.

Comment: @sixlettervariables Thank you, I am glad there there is less variety, in practice, than I initially thought.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unless you have a reason for choosing otherwise, the standard container that you should adopt by default is [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) (which is, by the way, the equivalent of .NET's `List<>` container).

`std::vector` allocates its element in a contiguous region of storage, which makes operations faster because of a higher rate of cache hits. This usually dominates the impact of linear computational complexity on operations such as insertions and removals from the middle of the container:

```
#include <vector> // <== Necessary for std::vector
#include <iostream> // <== Necessary for overloads of operator << and std::cout

std::vector<int> temp = { 1 };
temp.push_back(42);
std::cout << temp[0] << "," << temp[1];
```

Here is a [**live example**](http://ideone.com/RmHQUy).

For more technical information on why `std::vector` should be your default choice for a container, see [**this paper by Bjarne Stroustrup**](http://www.stroustrup.com/Software-for-infrastructure.pdf).

Comment: @juanchopanza: Technically yes. But still, vecotr has the better performance in most use cases. The idiom is to always use std::vector and only use something else if there is a good reason to do so. So logically std::vector is the equivalent of C#'s list from a logical point of view.

Comment: I don't think there is anything in my (deleted) comment that contradicts what you are saying.

Answer (score 6):

The exact equivalent is std::vector<>.  Exact same perf characteristics, only the exponential back-off growth algorithm for resizing the underlying array is slightly different.  Common std::vector<> implementations favor growing the array by x1.5, .NET collections grow by x2.

Note that it is **not** std::list<>, the equivalent for that one in .NET is LinkedList<>.  Best avoided, it has very poor cache locality.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `vector` as follows :

```
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
vector<double> v;
v.push_back(12);
```